# Argument 1 passed to::set must be an instance of App\date, string given

Tags: php, laravel, date

In my Model

```
 public function setReceptionDate(date $reception_date)
{
    $this->reception_date=$reception_date->date('Y-m-d');
  
}
public function getReceptionDate(): date
{
    return $this->Reception_date;
}
```

In my Controller

```
 $machine->setReceptionDate($reception_date);
```

In my blade.php

```
<label for="date" class="date-style">
<span id="dateFecha">Fecha de Recepción</span>
<input type="date" name="receptionDate" class="date-input-style" />
```

I don't know where is the error, please help

Comment: Inputs of type `date` will submit a string (just like the error suggests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 6.x or later, then you can just cast the reception_date property

```php
protected $casts = [
    'reception_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

No need for the Accessor and Mutator functions : `getReceptionDate` & `setReceptionDate`

And in the controller you can directly assign a valid string literal to the property

```php
$receptionDate = "2020-10-01";
$machine->reception_date = $receptionDate;
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your controller usage correctly

```
public function setReceptionDate(date $reception_date)
{
    $this->reception_date=$reception_date->date('Y-m-d');
  
}
```

Is receiving a string from the form. Yet you are treating it as if it's already a date class.

Try first turning it into a date class, or saving directly as is without the ->date function (as you seem to be attempting)